# React Native mapping two arrays

Tags: react-native

So I want to make a search filter. Currently the problem is I can only search for `title` in my data but I want to search for the `data` instead.
Basically I can only search for `Cluster1` and `Cluster2` but I actually want to search for `fun` and `cheerful` part instead.

This is my whole component

```
const ClusterData = [
{title: 'Cluster1', data: [{name: 'passionate'},{name: 'rousing'},{name: 'confident'},{name: 'boisterous'},{name: 'rowdy'}]},
{title: 'Cluster2', data: [{name: 'rollicking'},{name: 'cheerful'},{name: 'fun'},{name: 'sweet'},{name: 'amiable'},{name: 'natured'}]}
 ]

let userInput = ''

export default class TempScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = {
  search: false,
  dataToShow: []
}
  }

  componentWillMount(){
this.setState({dataToShow: ClusterData})
  }

  searchUpdated = (term) => {
let matchedItemsArray = []
if(term === ''){
  this.setState({search: false, dataToShow: ClusterData})
}else{
  this.setState({search:true, dataToShow: ClusterData}, function(){
    this.state.dataToShow.map((item) => {
      if(item.title.includes(term)){
        matchedItemsArray.push(item)
      }
    })
    this.setState({dataToShow:matchedItemsArray})
  })
}
  }

  render () {
return (
  <View>
    <TextInput 
      onChangeText={(term) => {this.searchUpdated(term)}} 
      style={styles.searchInput}
      placeholder="Type a mood to search"/>        
    <SectionList
      renderItem={({item}) => <SectionListItem itemName = {item.name}/>}
      renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <SectionHeader sectionTitle = {section.title}/>}
      sections={this.state.dataToShow}
    />
  </View>
)
  }
}

class SectionHeader extends React.Component{
render(){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{this.props.sectionTitle}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>Play</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
    }
  }

class SectionListItem extends React.Component{
  render(){
return(
  <View>
    <Text>{this.props.itemName}</Text>
  </View>
)
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: Already one discussion is going here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511791/creating-a-search-filter-react-native

Comment: On your setState callback try `let dumbData = ClusterData .data; dumbData.map((item) => { if(item.name.includes(term)){ matchedItemsArray.push(item) } })`

Comment: So I put that statement inside the `searchUpdated = (term)`?

Comment: Kindly undelete the accepted answer as i am making the other question as duplicate, which requires my accepted answer @Yvette Colomb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update this much piece on your code and try

```
searchUpdated = (term) => {
let matchedItemsArray = []
if(term === ''){
  this.setState({search: false, dataToShow: ClusterData})
}else{
  this.setState({search:true, dataToShow: ClusterData}, function(){
    ClusterData.map((item) => { 
        item.data.map(item1=>{
            if(item1.name == term){ 
               matchedItemsArray.push(item) 
           } 
          })
    })
    this.setState({dataToShow:matchedItemsArray})
  })
}
}
```

Comment: `undefined is not an object(evaluating 'dumbData.map')` I posted a screenshot of it

Comment: @KingJames i updated the code. Can you try this once

Comment: @KingJames happy to Know that :) Upvote and accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Instead, tailor the answer to the question asked. If the questions are exact duplicates of each other, please vote/flag to close instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to nested a second .map like that :

```
searchUpdated = (term) => {
    let matchedItemsArray = []
    if(term === ''){
        this.setState({search: false, dataToShow: ClusterData})
    }else{
        this.setState({search:true, dataToShow: ClusterData}, function(){
            this.state.dataToShow.map((item) => {
                 item.map((data) => {
                     if(data.name.includes(term)){
                         matchedItemsArray.push(data)
                     }
                 })
            })
       this.setState({dataToShow:matchedItemsArray})
       })
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I just add this code below the first searchUpdated statement?

Comment: Replace the first searchUpdated with the one I propose

Comment: My output has an error. `undefined is not a function(evaluating 'item.map')`